# How to install co-simulation support for myHDL

Tags: python, vhdl, verilog, test-bench, myhdl

I am trying to setup myHDL with Python2 on Windows 10 in order to work with VHDL/Verilog testbenches using Python for the source code. The corresponding instructions can be found [here](http://www.myhdl.org/start/installation.html).

I have successfully installed python, pip and then myHDL on my system. Now to setup co-simulation, I can't make sense of the instructions given:

> Co-simulation requires an additional installation step.
>
> To install co-simulation support:
>
> Go to the directory co-simulation/ for your target platform
>   and following the instructions in the README.txt file.

Which directory is being referred to here?  I can't find a co-simulation directory after installing myHDL in my `C:/Python27` directory/sub-directories.

The [FAQ](http://www.myhdl.org/support/faq.html) section addresses this issue by suggesting the use of Cygwin. Can someone suggest how to implement this or if there is an alternative method that I can work with?

Answer (score 1):

The cosimulation directory can be found in ~/.local/share/myhdl directory.

Answer (score 1):

For my Cygwin installation, it was here:

/usr/share/myhdl/cosimulation